# Get cell color from a conditionally formatted cell

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2013, excel-interop

I can read the background colors from normal cells, but if the cell has some sort of conditional formatting the background color obtained from `[RangeObject].Interior.Color` is not the same as the conditional formatter gave it.

My question is, is there a way to obtain this certain property or do I have to work my way around it, like programmatically set the same conditions in my code to change the background colors instead of read and write?

Answer (score 0):

If your version of Excel is 2010 or more recent, you can use the [Range.DisplayFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838814%28v=office.15%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Property.

Comment: this indeed gave me better results but, for example this cell http://i.imgur.com/SbvO2VL.png gave me CEC7FF (light purple) instead of  FFC7CE (light red)